# Reading specific column from a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I am writing some python code to practice for an exam in January. I need to read the second column into my code and print it out. If possible i also need to add data to specific columns.

The code i have tried is:

def view_this_weeks_sales(): #name of function

```
with open('employees-names1.csv ') as data: #name of csv file
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    first_column  = next(zip(*reader))
    print first_column
```

My file is below, it has four columns. Thanks in advance :)

Name of employee,Number of cars sold last week, Number of cars sold this week,Number of cars sold total (*all on one line*)

1,7,7,14

2,7,8,15

3,9,2,11

4,8,6,14

5,2,9,11

6,4,15,19

Total, ,47,84

Comment: You say you're writing python code to practice, yet I see no code in your question. You shouldn't ask stackoverflow to solve your homework for you. Please provide the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be

```
import csv
#replace the name with your actual csv file name
file_name = "data.csv" 
f = open(file_name)
csv_file = csv.reader(f)
second_column = [] #empty list to store second column values
for line in csv_file:
    second_column.append(line[1])
    print(line[1]) #index 1 for second column
```

Second_column variable will hold the necessary values. Hope this helps.